# how to translate the homepage with polylang?

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I use Polylang plugin to translate my English WordPress website to German, I was able to translate the pages and the posts I couldn't translate the homepage.

I use a static page for my homepage, I tried translating it but whenever I do changes the happen in both languages!

how can I create another static page for the second language?

Answer (score -1):

Try with `pll_e` in template and `pll_register_string` for function.